# JS console shows correct value and TypeError at the same time

Tags: javascript

I was trying to extract data from a JSON object
When I used console.log to test if I extracted it correctly, it shows the TypeError and the correct value at the same time.
I'm really confused.
[image: The console log result]
[image: my code]
[image: JSON format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an array object. Maybe the first item has the correct structure but your second doesn't.

Comment: That's the reason! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is not just object. It is an item/object from array of objects. So if content is the name of general array of objects then you can reach you want with:

`content[0].resource.identifier.value`